# Suppress nginx access denied error log

Tags: logging, nginx

I have some rules setup in nginx to deny access by IPs. This works great, but for each request from a denied IP, an error that starts with the following gets logged:

```
[error] 7325#0: *5761 access forbidden by rule, client...
```

Is there a way to suppress these "errors" from being logged?

Answer (score 4):

You can set error_log to less strict level, but you can lost important alerts in this case.

[Core functionality - error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)

```
error_log filename crit;
```

Comment: Thanks. We do care about other errors, and the access denied logs add a lot of unwanted noise to the mix. Is there a way to only suppress the access denied errors, or send them to another log?

Answer (score 3):

There is [better solution, suggested by upstream](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2149) - to use geo block with if to reject requests like:

```
geo $blocked {
    default 0;
    1.1.1.1/32 1;
}
...
server {

  if ($blocked) {
    return 444;
  }
}
```

Comment: People aren't glad of `if` in an NGINX context.

Comment: I know, "if is evil". But still, it is very useful. This is exactly the case where it is good solution.

Comment: I think most people vaguely recall that `if` doesn't behave like an `if` in most other languages, and then steer clear of it. But good if it works. 